# Why does my Haskell function return a type instead of a value?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I have difficulty understanding type creation in Haskell. I am trying to understand why the following Haskell function returns a type instead of a value:

```
data Exp = Enum Int

data Val = Vnum Int

eval :: Exp -> Val
eval (Enum x) = Vnum x

x :: Exp
x = Enum 2
```

When I run 'eval x', instead of returning 2 as I would expect, the interpreter returns 'eval x :: Val'. Enum and Vnum are merely tags, so basically, the eval function takes an "expression" as argument, which is in fact merely an integer, and returns a "value", which is also nothing more than an integer.

Like, of course eval x returns a Val, but why does the function not actually calculate the value and return it? I have the impression that the answer in kind of right in my face, but at the same time, I must be missing some elementary concept which is preventing me from noticing something that is probably obvious.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you show the logs of how you typed this into the interpreter? Because that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Were you perhaps trying to write `eval :: Exp -> Int; eval (Enum x) = x`? `Exp` and `Val` are essentially the same type, just using different names to wrap an `Int` value. (They are what we call *isomorphic* types; you can convert a value of one to a value of the other without losing any information.)

Comment: @chepner I expect two different types is intended. This looks like the prelude to an evaluator. The language being evaluated will doubtless make a distinction between expressions and values (`2 + 2` is a valid expression but not a valid value). So we need two types to distinguish, even if in the early stages there's no difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does my Haskell function return a type

it doesn't. Your function works just fine and `eval x` does indeed give a *value* of type `Val`.

However note that an interpreter has no way to display this value – as far as it is concerned, this is a completely opaque type. At least GHCi makes this pretty clear:

```
<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show Val) arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Only if you *say* that you're really only interested in the type, by using the `:t` or `:type` directive, will it show just that:

```
> :t eval (Enum 2)
eval (Enum 2) :: Val
```

The easiest way to enable printing of values is to *derive* a `Show` instance:

```
data Val = Vnum Int   -- incidentally, this should probably be `newtype`,
 deriving (Show)      -- rather than `data`
```

```
> eval (Enum 2)
Vnum 2
```